# Remove unused (generated) columns

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, cursor

I am trying to split name values to analyze them afterwards. To do so, I generate 15 columns in T-SQL and then use an UDF (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26937.t-sql-splitting-a-string-into-multiple-columns.aspx) to split a column 'value' into the new columns (using space as separator). I get the following results, as intended, so far, so good...

```
id|value  |col_1|col_2|col_3|col_4|col_5|col_6|col_7|col_8|col_9|col_10|col_11|col_12|col_13|col_14|col_15
1 |xxx    |x    |x    |x    |     |     |     |     |     |     |      |      |      |      |      |     
2 |x      |x    |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |      |      |      |      |      |
3 |xxxxxxx|x    |x    |x    |x    |x    |x    |x    |     |     |      |      |      |      |      |
4 |xxxx   |x    |x    |x    |x    |     |     |     |     |     |      |      |      |      |      |
```

Happy with my solution I started on the code to really analyze the seperate parts. My colleague however, came up with a small nonsense-note, he said the columns that are not used, should be removed. And because I am appointed to help colleagues instead of telling them how silly their questions are, I said I'd look into it.

The thing is that my ego does not allow me to use 15 hard-coded lines for this. I'd really like to do this with a cursor, so that the code keeps working if later on I need to parse much longer strings (which btw is actually assumable). I use a number in the cursor to create a column name. Then I thought it would be a good idea to use a 'select 1 from #1 where len(column_name)'-query to see if the column is in use. But now I am stuck creating the dynamic sql that include the created column_name. Which is a problem, because I need that same column_name to actually remove it when found empty.

```
while @count < @max_nr_columns
begin
set @colname = 'part' + convert(varchar(255), (@count + 1))
declare @max_col_real nvarchar(4000)-- = N'max_col_real_is_empty'
declare @mc int = 0
exec('sp_executesql (select 1 from #1 where ' + @colname + ' is not null), N''@max_col_real nvarchar(4000) output'', @max_col_real output')
set @max_col_real = (@sql)
set @count = @count + 1
end
print @max_col_real
```

It throws an error about a comma, which means that the problem resides in the exec-line. Can anyone point me in the right direction for removing column 8-15? Or tell me what I am doing wrong in the above code?

I am using SQL2014, but like to stay downwards compatible until 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pivot to suppress null values. Pivot,Stuff and FOR XML should be available since 2008.

So example could be

**SQL Code UPDATE with DYNAMIC UNPIVOT**

```
   Create table #temp (id int, value nvarchar(50),col_1 nvarchar(50),col_2 nvarchar(50),col_3 nvarchar(50),col_4 nvarchar(50),col_5 nvarchar(50),col_6 nvarchar(50),col_7 nvarchar(50),col_8 nvarchar(50),col_9 nvarchar(50))

insert into #temp
values


(1 ,'xxx'    ,'x','x','x',null,null,null,null,null,null),    
(2 ,'x'      ,'x',null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null), 
(3 ,'xxxxxxx','x','x','x','x','x','x','x',null,null),  
(4 ,'xxxx'   ,'x','x','x','x',null,null,null,null,null) 




declare @gruppe nvarchar(max)
      declare @gruppeSql nvarchar(max)
      declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
      DECLARE myCustomers CURSOR FOR

Select [Name] from tempdb.sys.columns where object_id = object_id('tempdb..#temp') 
and [name] like 'col%' 

      set @gruppeSql = ''
      OPEN myCustomers
       FETCH NEXT FROM myCustomers INTO @gruppe
      IF (@@FETCH_STATUS>=0)
      BEGIN
      SET @gruppeSql = @gruppeSql +'[' +@gruppe+']'
      FETCH NEXT FROM myCustomers INTO @gruppe
       END
       WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS<>-1)
       BEGIN
       IF (@@FETCH_STATUS<>-2)

       SET @gruppeSql = @gruppeSql  + ',[' +@gruppe+']'
       FETCH NEXT FROM myCustomers INTO @gruppe
       END
       CLOSE myCustomers
       DEALLOCATE myCustomers 

      SET @gruppeSql = replace(@gruppesql,'''','')
      print @gruppeSql
      --select @gruppeSql
       SET @SQL = '


        SELECT distinct Pets = ''Select'' + STUFF((SELECT N'', '' + cols 
  FROM (select distinct cols from #temp a

UNPIVOT (Rowno for Cols in('+@gruppeSql+')) as pvy ) AS p2

   FOR XML PATH(N'''')), 1, 2, N'' '')'




      print @sql
      exec(@sql)
      drop table #temp
```

Comment: Thank you @PlaidDK. This does the trick in a creative way, pivoting the data might just be the right nudge. The thing though is that this still requires me to hard-code col_1 to col_9. In my current code only 15 columns are created, but I have a variable to use later on, if there is a situation where I need to generate (and fill) 1000 columns. I will play and try to make the unpivot line dynamic, hopefully that will work.

Comment: You can easily make your unpivot dynamic. Make a cursor on above results a loop through them and concatenate into  a string.

Comment: @Steef i just made it dynamic for you. Look at update. And you can of cause do the same thing with a table instead of a temp table which i would recommend.

Comment: This is it, I can use this! Thanks a lot for your time and mind!

Comment: @Steef No worries . Remember to mark it as correct so other people can benefit from it. Thanks.

Comment: You can also do like this instead of a cursor  `DECLARE @str nvarchar(max)

  set @Str = STUFF((
Select Distinct ','+[Name] from tempdb.sys.columns where object_id = object_id('tempdb..#temp') 
and [name] like 'col%' FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
PRINT @str ` and then use @str instead of @gruppeSql - But it does the same just less code